# Why this doesn't type checks?

Tags: haskell

A mutable hashmap from ByteString to Integer. Should be easy but can understand why it does not type checks. Should I notate some type manualy?

```
import           Control.Monad.ST               ( ST, runST)
import qualified Data.HashTable.Class          as HC
import           Data.HashTable.Class           ( HashTable )
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8     ( ByteString )

fourSizedTable :: HashTable h => ST s (h s ByteString Integer)
fourSizedTable = HC.newSized 4

asList :: ST s [(ByteString, Integer)]
asList = fourSizedTable >>= HC.toList
```

fails with the following message:

> • No instance for (HashTable h0) 
>     arising from a use of ‘fourSizedTable’
>   • In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘fourSizedTable’
>     In the expression: fourSizedTable >>= HC.toList
>     In an equation for ‘asList’: asList = fourSizedTable >>= HC.toList

Comment: I think the problem here is that the `h` is "erased" from the type signature, and therefore now you have a function where it is no longer clear what hastable you are actually using.

Comment: The type error should also have included a statement that the type `h0` is ambiguous, which is an important clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the `h` dissapears from the signature of your `asList` function, so you can no longer specify the `h` through the signature (or through the use of `asList`). As a result, Haskell no longer knows hat `HashTable` instance to pick here, hence the error.

You can for example specify one, with an explicit signature, or with the `TypeApplications` extension. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import           Control.Monad.ST               ( ST, runST)
import qualified Data.HashTable.ST.Basic       as HT
import qualified Data.HashTable.Class          as HC
import           Data.HashTable.Class           ( HashTable )
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8     ( ByteString )

fourSizedTable :: HashTable h => ST s (h s ByteString Integer)
fourSizedTable = HC.newSized 4

asList :: ST s [(ByteString, Integer)]
asList = fourSizedTable @HT.HashTable >>= HC.toList
```

We here thus pick a specific `HashTable` instance, and therefore there is no confusion anymore.